# 'No Matches found' message when i scroll the window up and down in Select2 Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I am using Select2 for Multiselect , the issue that i am facing now it displays

'No Matches found' message when i scroll the window up and down.

For example,

- If i Select, 3 values and delete those 3 values
- and then If I scroll Up and Down , then it dispalys 3

  'No Matches found'.

I tried to add

```
 .select2-no-results {
 display: none !important;
 }
```

The problem here it will stop display even if there is no such result.